# Two divs toggle, merge multiple javascript click hooks into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I have the following:

```
<script>
    $('#nav-close').on('click', function(){

      var mover = $('#mover');

      // register is not visible
      if(mover.css('opacity') === '1'){
        mover.css({'opacity': '0'});
      } else {
        mover.css({'opacity': '1'});
      }

    });
    $('#nav-expander').on('click', function(){

      var mover = $('#mover');

      // register is not visible
      if(mover.css('opacity') === '1'){
        mover.css({'opacity': '0'});
      } else {
        mover.css({'opacity': '1'});
      }

    });
</script>
```

How do I combine these two into one - logic such as below for a more efficient script:

```
    $('#nav-close' || '#nav-expander').on('click', function(){
```

...

Comment: replace || with a comma?

Comment: Tried that - no luck ...('#nav-close', '#nav-expander')...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `,` instead of `||` .Refer [jquery multiple selector documentation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMromy-5bUAhULO48KHViiCFoQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fmultiple-selector%2F&usg=AFQjCNExxu-raZM1KHc0xcuSDUk8j-OzkA&sig2=gCkxtCngmZPjapSJ0-GO2Q)

```
$('#nav-close,#nav-expander').on('click', function() {
  var mover = $('#mover');
  // register is not visible
  if (mover.css('opacity') === '1') {
    mover.css({
      'opacity': '0'
    });
  } else {
    mover.css({
      'opacity': '1'
    });
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please see:-
    Multiple Selector at => http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/
    Note, the double quotes around your div selectors. ;)

$("#nav-close, #nav-expander").click('click', function() {
var mover = $('#mover');
// register is not visible
if (mover.css('opacity') === '1') {
    mover.css({
    'opacity': '0'
});
} else {
    mover.css({
    'opacity': '1'
});
}
```

});